# learn python the hard way exercise 20 help

Tags: python

for the extras of exercise 20 i was told to comment what i think each line does. seek i found confusing. if anyone is willing to check out my comments on the source to see if i understand correctly. i could skip it but i feel its important i understand this.

thanks

```
from sys import argv #imports argv from sys moduel 

script, input_file = argv #unpacks the startup arguments to script and input_file variables

def print_all(f): #defines a function that uses the read() function on whatever is in the parameter(current_file in this case)
    print f.read()

def rewind(f): #not a clue what this does really...moves to byte 0 of the file??
    f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line_count, f): #sets a function that reads a line from the current_file
    print line_count, f.readline()

current_file = open(input_file)

print 'first of all, lets read the wole file:\n'

print_all(current_file)

print 'now lets rewind, kind of like a tape'
rewind(current_file)

print 'lets print 3 lines:'

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

Comment: thanks guys, and the rest is accurate?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it sets the file's current position to the first byte. This can be seen in the [documentation for file.seek](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek):

> `file.seek(offset[, whence])`
>
> Sets the file’s current position, like stdio‘s fseek(). The whence argument is optional and defaults to os.SEEK_SET or 0 (absolute file positioning); other values are os.SEEK_CUR or 1 (seek relative to the current position) and os.SEEK_END or 2 (seek relative to the file’s end). There is no return value.

Note that since you didn't supply a value for the `whence` parameter, the default value `os.SEEK_SET` is used. This means absolute file positioning (i.e. relative to the start of the file).

Answer (score 2):

[file.seek](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) goes back to the beginning of the file. Without it, you can only iterate through the file once.